# GCF and differences of roots

Tags: algebra-precalculus, gcd-and-lcm

I found a problem that was asking about the GCF and the minimum difference between two roots, and I was wondering if anyone could help.

"Given two perfect squares, m and n GCF(m,n) = 4 and mn=2304. Find the minimum positive difference in their positive roots."

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried factoring $2304$?  Have you found $LCM(m,n)$? What have you tried?

Comment: Calculate. We have $m=4a^2$ and $n=4b^2$, where $\gcd(a,b)=1$. Also, $16a^2b^2=2304$.

Comment: So far, I have found out that the sqrt of 2304 is 48, which I used to get sqrt(mn) = 48, but haven't managed to get any further there. I found out that the LCM is 2304/4 = 576. I know that the answer has something to do with finding the largest and smallest powers of each prime number in the prime factorization, but I haven't managed to figure anything else out.

Comment: Wouldn't 4* a perfect square be a number that isn't a perfect square though?

Comment: No, if you multiply a square by $4$ (or any other square) the result is a square.

Comment: Oh. Is that because 4 is a perfect square as well?

Comment: So, assuming that m=4a^2 and n=4n^2, how would this lead you to get the minimum positive difference? So far I have taken the sqrt(16a^2 * b^2 = 2304) and gotten 4ab=48, ab=12. Where would you go from there?

Comment: I think the question could be phrased a little better. The way it is written, it looks like $m$ and $n$ are fixed but arbitrary, when in reality, we're "quantifying" over them.

Answer (score 0):

So $m=4a$ and $n = 4b$. If $mn = 2304$ then $16ab = 2304$, or ab = 144 find all positive perfect squares that multiply to make $144$ and go from there.